# Typoscript change a tag params if level 3 menu exists

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i have a menu which looks something like this

```
-AAA
  -SUB_A1
  -SUB_A2
  -SUB_A3
-BBB
  -SUB_B1
     -SUB_B1_1
     -SUB_B1_2
  -SUB_B2
     -SUB_B2_1
     -SUB_B2_2
```

In other words, i have sometimes two levels of navigation and sometimes three. I need to check if the menu point has three or two levels and need to change the atagparams of the first level accordingly.

```
1 = TMENU
1 {
    wrap =  <ul class="menu sitemenu-submenu-light sitemenu-extra-strong sitemenu-extra-no-arrows">|</ul>

    expAll = 1
    noBlur = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="mega-menu">|</li>
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        #ATagParams ="topmenu-item text-hover-blue"
        ATagParams = class="menu-item menu-separator"
    }
    ACT < .NO
    ACT = 1
    ACT{
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current mega-menu">|</li>
   }
}
```

So i need to change

```
ATagParams ="topmenu-item text-hover-blue"
```

to

```
ATagParams = class="menu-item menu-separator"
```

if a level 3 is available. Is it possible or do i need to work around this?

KR
Adi

Comment: If you are familiar with ext:vhs, you can try to play with `<v:page.menu deferred="TRUE">`. Check [Deferred rendering](https://worksonmymachine.org/blog/a-guide-to-menu-rendering-with-fluidtypo3) section.

Comment: This was a real usefull hint. Thanks, it was so much easier to create a menu without typoscript.

Comment: Nice, that this helped. Don't you mind posting an answer with your solution here, so I can upvote it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the useful tip to use the extention VHS i now created the navigation solely with fluid viewhelpers. The solution works for me, for now. The main part is looping through the items and set a variable to "hasSubs" and later check if it is true or false

```
    {namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<v:page.menu>
    <div class="abc-menu sitemenu-submenu-light sitemenu-extra-strong sitemenu-extra-no-arrows">
        <f:for each="{menu}" as="item">
            <v:variable.set name="hasSub" value="0" />
            <f:if condition="{item.hasSubPages}">
                <v:page.menu pageUid="{item.uid}">
                         <span style="display: none">
                These aren't the droids you are looking for</span>
                    <f:for each="{menu}" as="subItemCheck">
                        <f:if condition="{subItemCheck.hasSubPages}">
                            <f:then>
                                <v:variable.set name="hasSub" value="1" />
                            </f:then>
                        </f:if>
                    </f:for>
                </v:page.menu>
            </f:if>

            <f:if condition="{hasSub} == 1">
                <f:then>
                    <li class="mega-menu">
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    <li>
                </f:else>
            </f:if>

            <f:link.page pageUid="{item.uid}" class="menu-item menu-separator">{item.linktext}</f:link.page>
            <f:if condition="{item.hasSubPages}">
                <v:page.menu pageUid="{item.uid}">
                    <f:if condition="{hasSub} == 1">
                        <f:then>
                            <div class="abc-mega" data-columns="5">
                        </f:then>
                        <f:else>
                            <ul>
                        </f:else>
                    </f:if>
                    <f:for each="{menu}" as="subItem">
                        <f:if condition="{subItem.hasSubPages}">
                            <f:then>
                                <v:page.menu pageUid="{subItem.uid}">
                                    <v:variable.set name="menuHasThreeSubs" value="1" />
                                    <div class="abc-mega-section">
                                        <h4 data-role="title">
                                            <f:link.page pageUid="{subItem.uid}" class="menu-item">{subItem.linktext}</f:link.page>
                                        </h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <f:for each="{menu}" as="subSubItem">
                                                <li>
                                                    <f:link.page pageUid="{subSubItem.uid}" class="menu-item">{subSubItem.linktext}</f:link.page>
                                                </li>
                                            </f:for>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </v:page.menu>
                            </f:then>
                            <f:else>
                                <f:if condition="{hasSub} == 1">
                                    <f:then>
                                        <div class="abc-mega-section">
                                            <h4 data-role="title">
                                                <f:link.page pageUid="{subItem.uid}" class="menu-item">{subItem.linktext}</f:link.page>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </f:then>
                                    <f:else>
                                        <li>
                                            <f:link.page pageUid="{subItem.uid}" class="menu-item">{subItem.linktext}</f:link.page>
                                        </li>
                                    </f:else>
                                </f:if>
                            </f:else>
                        </f:if>
                    </f:for>
                    <f:if condition="{hasSub} == 1">
                        <f:then>
                            </div>
                        </f:then>
                        <f:else>
                             </ul>
                    </f:else>
                    </f:if>
                </v:page.menu>
            </f:if>
    </f:for>
</div>
</v:page.menu>
```